Add field to large collection in mongoDB
I have a large collection (200 million documents) where I must add a new field, hashedContainerId. It is the hash of another field that I have for each document.
My idea to process this is to:

build a index on hashedContainerId;
query for a page of 50/100 documents filtering for hashedContainerId not existing (corresponding query would be something like {'hashedContainerId': {'$exists': False}});
compute locally the hashes and execute a bulk operation of update;
loop to step 2.

Is this doable? I fear that the more documents I update, the slower the query {'hashedContainerId': {'$exists': False}} becomes because documents must be scanned each time.
Thank you for reading so far!

Make a simple update if you can compute the hash with native aggregation pipeline (or use $function), otherwise a plain Bulk update.

@WernfriedDomscheit can aggregation pipeline/bulk update work even though I am quite confident the operation will go in timeout or crash at some point? Can I restart it without having to rescan all the collection? Thank you for your reply.

Just try the update. In case it fails, then you may add a condition but I don't see any reason to use any condition for the initial run.

Check explain - if {'hashedContainerId': {'$exists': False}} doesn't use the index, try with {'hashedContainerId': null}
